# PRC REPORT: Carriage Return in Column to add to concatenated fields

Tags: sas

I'm created a PROC REPORT that has a number of columns that are in the input dataset and some others that are created in COMPUTE blocks. Some of the columns are created using cats() to concatenate the values of others etc.

Is it possible to insert a carriage return into a column using `ods escapechar='^' ;`? I haven't been successful in doing this. For one of the columns, I would like to do this, but I can't make it work: `_C4_ = cats(_C2_,"^", _C3);` Columns *C2* and *C3* are computed, numeric columns.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think it depends on your ODS destination.

Comment: I think my solution works for most ods destinations--just need to include the character you meant to escape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on your ODS destination, but you need to actually do something after your escape character.

The escape character just tells SAS that the following character is something special and not regular text.

I think what you want is `_C4_ = cats(_C2_,'^n',_C3_);`

^n should escape the "n" which will be interpreted as a newline character.

Here is some sample code:

```
data test;
input name $ var1 var2 var3;
datalines;
bob 1 2 3
ted 4 5 6
jon 7 8 9
;
run;

ods escapechar='^';

proc report data=test;
  columns name var1 var2 calc var3;
  define calc /computed;
  compute calc / character length=30;
    calc = cats(_C2_,'^n',_C3_);
  endcomp;
run;
```

This works for me in EG's native results output and should work in a PDF or other line-break supporting destination.  The define line is not strictly necessary (and in fact when I exclude it, it right justifies the column), but I assume you would be including them anyways to set column titles and formats.

If you want to force var1 and var2 into a specific format, you can replace them in the cats function with something like `put(_C2_,comma16.1)`

Lots of cool stuff you can do with ODS styles and an escape character (like underline subheaders in PDF output or highlight alternating rows different colors)
For reference of some basics: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/099-2007.pdf